# что значит слово "контракт" в джава?

Tags: java

что все-таки значит слово "контракт" применяемое к методам и тд в контексте джавы?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Тоже, что и в русском языке - некоторую договоренность между сторонами. В случае с программированием - какие условия использования у сущностей, например для соблюдения одного из принципов SOLID "подстановка Барбары Лисков" - чтобы пользователи знали, чего ожидать от сущности, которой пользуются.

Яркий пример, когда вы заключаете контракт на ремонтные работы - сроки выполнения, условия работы и т.д. и т.п. Для программирования это проецируется напрямую.

Comment: спасибо! прояснилось

Answer (score 2):

`Контракт` метода - это сигнатура метода в сочетании с типом возвращаемого значения и бросаемыми исключениями.

`Сигнатура` же в свою очередь - это имя метода плюс параметры (порядок параметров важен).

public String **someAction(int x, String y)** throws Exception — *сигнатура*

public **String someAction(int x, String y) throws Exception** — *контракт*